# What's wrong with my transition, using React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, tailwind-css

```js
const style = {
   transition: "width 1s 0s"
}

const ReusableHeadersNav = ({ show, setShow, children,modalWidth,setModalWidth }: IProps) => {

    if(show){
        setTimeout(() => {
            setModalWidth(20)
        }, 1000)
    
    }

    if (!show) return null

    return (
        <div className=' sm:fixed hidden inset-10 z-10  sm:flex justify-center items-center b  bg-opacity-0   ' onClick={() => setShow(false)} >

            <div style={style} className={`sm:h-[100vh]  border-r-[1px] border-l-[1px] b  fixed left-16  bg-white  rounded-r-2xl    w-[${modalWidth}%]`} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                <div className='flex  py-4 items-center 0'>
                    {children}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

At first everything was working, but when I ran `npm start` again it stopped working. I don't understand whats happened, since I didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you specify what the expected behavior is and what you mean by "it stopped working"? If you mean there's an error message, please provide it. If you mean it doesn't look as expected, please show how it's looking.